# Ranking Variables by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rank

I am trying to rank a variable within groups of two other variables.  I am using `frank` in `data.table`.  I can't seem to get the `by` parameter to work the way I expect

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(indpn = c(170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 9870, 
9870, 9870, 9870, 9870, 9870), occpn = c(6050, 9130, 205, 5120, 
5740, 6005, 3930, 700, 1410, 3645, 1050, 150), ncwc = c(258575, 
4747, 10742, 205, 867, 11026, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000181ef0>)
```

This is the code I am use

```
z[ , therank := frank( -ncwc , ties.method ="min" ) , by = .(indpn, occpn) ]
```

This is what I am receiving:

```
    indpn occpn   ncwc therank
 1:   170  6050 258575       1
 2:   170  9130   4747       1
 3:   170   205  10742       1
 4:   170  5120    205       1
 5:   170  5740    867       1
 6:   170  6005  11026       1
 7:  9870  3930      0       1
 8:  9870   700      0       1
 9:  9870  1410      0       1
10:  9870  3645      0       1
11:  9870  1050      0       1
12:  9870   150      0       1
```

I expect the therank variable to return 1,4,3,6,5,2,1,1,1,1,1,1

Comment: Why are you grouping by `occpn`?  This works : `z[ , therank := frank( -ncwc , ties.method ="min" ) ,indpn]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comment grouping only by `indpn` gives the expected output

```
library(data.table)
z[ , therank := frank(-ncwc , ties.method ="min" ) ,indpn]
z

#    indpn occpn   ncwc therank
# 1:   170  6050 258575       1
# 2:   170  9130   4747       4
# 3:   170   205  10742       3
# 4:   170  5120    205       6
# 5:   170  5740    867       5
# 6:   170  6005  11026       2
# 7:  9870  3930      0       1
# 8:  9870   700      0       1
# 9:  9870  1410      0       1
#10:  9870  3645      0       1
#11:  9870  1050      0       1
#12:  9870   150      0       1
```

However, note how `frank` behaves. Is this output that you are looking for ?

```
z$ncwc[12] <- -1
z[ , therank := frank( -ncwc , ties.method ="min" ) ,indpn]
z
#    indpn occpn   ncwc therank
# 1:   170  6050 258575       1
# 2:   170  9130   4747       4
# 3:   170   205  10742       3
# 4:   170  5120    205       6
# 5:   170  5740    867       5
# 6:   170  6005  11026       2
# 7:  9870  3930      0       1
# 8:  9870   700      0       1
# 9:  9870  1410      0       1
#10:  9870  3645      0       1
#11:  9870  1050      0       1
#12:  9870   150     -1       6
```

If you expect the last value to be 2 and not 6 you can use `match` with `unique`

```
z[order(-ncwc) , therank := match(ncwc, unique(ncwc)) ,indpn]
z
#    indpn occpn   ncwc therank
# 1:   170  6050 258575       1
# 2:   170  9130   4747       4
# 3:   170   205  10742       3
# 4:   170  5120    205       6
# 5:   170  5740    867       5
# 6:   170  6005  11026       2
# 7:  9870  3930      0       1
# 8:  9870   700      0       1
# 9:  9870  1410      0       1
#10:  9870  3645      0       1
#11:  9870  1050      0       1
#12:  9870   150     -1       2
```